# Cannot enter null into nullable field with foreign key

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, dbcontext

I am trying to enter `NULL` into a nullable field with a foreign key.  I am using C# `DbContext`. I am able to do this in SQL Server, but when I try to do this in C# I get the following error message:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
>   "FK_Cadastral_Project_Alpha". The conflict occurred in database "RMIS_DB_DEV", table "dbo.Cadastral_Valid_Alpha", column 'Code'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Run SQLProfiler and find the exact SQL that is being sent to the database and you'll have a better idea of the problem.  If that doesn't help please add the SQL to your question.

Comment: Can be C# model out-of-sync with the database. Please try to refresh/recreate the model in your VS project.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?